# Why is this function, related to SVM derivation, non-convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I'm working through a support vector machines tutorial. In eventually deriving the solvable objective function, the following objective function (to be maximized) was proposed, but dismissed as non-convex (i.e., it's negative is non-convex). Why is it non-convex?

$$
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\lVert#1\rVert}
f(\hat{\gamma}, w, b) = \frac{\hat{\gamma}}{\norm{w}} = \min_{i=1, \dots, m} y^{(i)} \left( \frac{w^{T}}{\norm{w}} x^{(i)} + \frac{b}{\norm{w}} \right)
$$

where the label variable $y^{(i)} \in \{-1,1\}$, the feature vector $x^{(i)} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, $w \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, and $b \in \mathbb{R}$.

The (convex) constraints are:
$$
y^{(i)} (w^{T}x^{(i)} + b) \ge \hat{\gamma},\; i=1, \dots, m.
$$

Comment: Please define what spaces your variables live in and any constraints on them.  And in which variable is it non-convex with respect to.

Comment: @muaddib Updated to define spaces and added the constraints. I do not know in which variable it is non-convex.

Comment: Perhaps I'm overcomplicating this. If I were to consider minimizing $(-1/\lvert w \rvert)$ (i.e., let $w \in \mathbb{R}^{1}$), it's clear that this is not convex wrt $w$.

Comment: I think you're right (re: overcomplicating). It seems a bit odd to me to ask "why is this function non-convex?" It is non-convex because, well, it is not convex. Convex functions are the *exception*, not the rule. If you can't prove something is not convex, you must necessarily *assume* that it is not. Have you made any attempt at all to prove that it is convex?

Comment: Ah,  see that you have, given your analysis of $-1/|w|$... carry on, jolly good, :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments (thanks Michael Grant), I was overcomplicating things. It's easy to show non-convexity with respect to $w$. First, consider $w \in \mathbb{R}^{1}$ and show that (the negative of) $f$ is not convex by checking a couple of values of $w$. Secondly, note that $f$ is undefined for $w = \vec{0}$, implying that the $w$ domain of $f$ is non-convex in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.