# How to efficiently find all solutions of equation $(A + \text{sgn}(x)\text{sgn}(x)^T )x= y x$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

Consider the following equation:

$$\left (A + \text{sgn}(x)\text{sgn}(x)^T  \right )x= y \, x  \tag{1} $$

where $A$ is an $n \times n$ **symmetric** matrix. The variables are $y \in \mathbb R, x \in \mathbb R ^n$ with $\| x \|_2=1$. Note this can be equivalently written as

$$Ax +\|x\|_1 \text{sgn}(x) =y \, x.$$

To avoid trivial or degenerate solutions, we restrict ourselves to the solutions $x \neq 0$ with $\| x \|=1$; indeed, any solution $x$ of this equation remains a solution after a linear transformation.

Such an equation appears in non-convex optimization, where **all** of its solutions need to be found so that the problem is fully solved. In fact the original system that needs to be solved is of the form

$$\color{blue}{\left [ \left(A + \text{sgn}(x)\text{sgn}(x)^T  \right )x- y \, x \right ] \odot \text{sgn}(x) =0.}, \tag{2} $$

which reduces to the above system if we assume $x_i \neq 0, i=,\dots,n$. Also, if $A$ is a diagonal matrix, the two systems (1) and (2) become the same.

**A naïve approach** to solve the equation (1) is to fix $\text{sgn}(x)=a$ for any $a \in \{-1,1 \}^n$, and then solve the system. One can see that if $a$ is considered, $-a$ is not needed to be assessed as both produce the same matrix of $aa^T$. Hence, $2^{n-1}$ cases should be examined. After fixing $\text{sgn}(x)=a$, each solution $y$ and $x$ of the resulting system:

$$(A + aa^T )x= y x$$

is nothing but an eigenvalue and its normalized eigenvector of matrix $A+aa^T.$ Such a solution is a correct solution for our equation only if  $\text{sgn}(x)=a$ or $\text{sgn}(x)=-a.$

When $A=0$, for each $a$, $\text{rank}(aa^T)=1$, and the system has the following $n$ solutions $(x,y)$:

$$(e_1,1),\dots, (e_n,1).$$

I have two related questions:

> How many solutions can this system have (my guess the number of solutions is of order $O(n)$ though $2^{n-1}$ different possibilities can be obtained by fixing $\text{sgn}(x)$)?

> Is there any efficient procedure to find all solutions of the above system (the computational complexity of the naïve approach is of exponential order)?

Comment: Shouldn't $\operatorname{sgn}(x) \in \{-1,0,1\}^n$?

Comment: @BrianMoehring I think the $0$ case is covered by assuming that if a solution with $x_i=0$ for some $i$ is obtained, it is accepted in the checking phase, while $\text{sgn}(x_i)$ is fixed to $-1$ or $1$. Is that correct?

Comment: If $x_i=0$, the situation of the equation is the same as the case where the $i$th row of the matrix $\text{sgn}(x)\text{sgn}(x)^T$ becomes zero by setting $\text {sgn}(x_i)=0$. It is why I think we can ignore the 0 case to simplify the search procedure.

Comment: Where did this question come from. Context please

Comment: @Mike I obtained this equation after applying  the KKT conditions in this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4877362/1231520. I think it is an interesting equation. I am wondering whether the  naive approach described in the OP is the only approach or not?

Comment: Do we really need to convert the problem to an equivalent problem to discuss the KKT conditions? I think this can be written without this step and nondifferentiability should not be an issue! See: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ggordon/10725-F12/slides/16-kkt.pdf.

Comment: @Sam I think using subgradients, a similar system can be obtained, while I cannot see how to deal with the fact that at $0$ the subdifferential of $|x|$ is $ [-1,1]$.